# Deserialize a json object with different structure and same name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, imdb

I write an app that gets IMDb movie information by scraping movie page source. Some of the movie data in page source are in JSON format with movie schema from "Schema.org".

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt7131622/",
  "name": "Once Upon a Time... in Hollywood",
  "genre": [
    "Comedy",
    "Drama"
  ],
  "actor": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0000138/",
      "name": "Leonardo DiCaprio"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0000093/",
      "name": "Brad Pitt"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm3053338/",
      "name": "Margot Robbie"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0386472/",
      "name": "Emile Hirsch"
    }
  ],
  "director": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "url": "/name/nm0000233/",
    "name": "Quentin Tarantino"
  },
  "creator": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0000233/",
      "name": "Quentin Tarantino"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0050868/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0452101/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0159772/"
    }
}
```

I made a "Movie" class to deserialize the JSON object. There is a property `Person` class with the name "Director".

```
internal class ImdbJsonMovie
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public List<string> Genre { get; set; }
        public List<ImdbJsonPerson> Actor { get; set; }
        public ImdbJsonPerson Director { get; set; }
        //public string[] Creator { get; set; }
    }
```

It's OK. But the problem is some movies such as "The Matrix" have more than one director.

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt0133093/",
  "name": "The Matrix",
  "genre": [
    "Action",
    "Sci-Fi"
  ],
  "actor": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0000206/",
      "name": "Keanu Reeves"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0000401/",
      "name": "Laurence Fishburne"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0005251/",
      "name": "Carrie-Anne Moss"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0915989/",
      "name": "Hugo Weaving"
    }
  ],
  "director": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0905154/",
      "name": "Lana Wachowski"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0905152/",
      "name": "Lilly Wachowski"
    }
  ],
  "creator": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0905152/",
      "name": "Lilly Wachowski"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "url": "/name/nm0905154/",
      "name": "Lana Wachowski"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0002663/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0108864/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0060075/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0019968/"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "/company/co0070636/"
    }
}
```

So it must be `List<Person>`.

```
internal class ImdbJsonMovie
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public List<string> Genre { get; set; }
        public List<ImdbJsonPerson> Actor { get; set; }
        public List<ImdbJsonPerson> Director { get; set; }
        //public string[] Creator { get; set; }
    }
```

Another problem is how to deserialize creator property that is made by the `Person` class and `Organization` class.

So the question is "How to deserialize this complex JSON object?"

Thank you

Comment: I guess, that you should write your own converter for these properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Piotr. It completely worked. because your first part of the answer was not correct for me, I rewrite your response as an answer.

as you said the correct answer was in this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n

So I made this class.

```
class JsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<T>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and changed my Movie Class to this.

```
internal class ImdbJsonMovie
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("genre")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<string>))]
    public List<string> Genre { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contentRating")]
    public string ContentRating { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("actor")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<ImdbJsonTypeEnum>))]
    public List<ImdbJsonTypeEnum> Actor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("director")] 
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<ImdbJsonTypeEnum>))]
    public List<ImdbJsonTypeEnum> Director { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("creator")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<ImdbJsonTypeEnum>))]
    public List<ImdbJsonTypeEnum> Creator { get; set; }
}
```

and this Enum

```
public class ImdbJsonTypeEnum
{
    [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public enum TypeEnum
    {
        Organization,
        Person
    };
}
```

It worked for one director and multi director movies.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Did you try: https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp? It can generate model in C# for you, which is very good begining for further changes (if the Schema has to be different according to different json responses)

I did enter your JSON and the model created is following:

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Movies
    {
        [JsonProperty("@context")]
        public Uri Context { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("@type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("genre")]
        public List<string> Genre { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("actor")]
        public List<Tor> Actor { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("director")]
        public List<Tor> Director { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("creator")]
        public List<Tor> Creator { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Tor
    {
        [JsonProperty("@type")]
        public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TypeEnum { Organization, Person };

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                TypeEnumConverter.Singleton,
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class TypeEnumConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(TypeEnum) || t == typeof(TypeEnum?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
            var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Organization":
                    return TypeEnum.Organization;
                case "Person":
                    return TypeEnum.Person;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type TypeEnum");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (untypedValue == null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;
            }
            var value = (TypeEnum)untypedValue;
            switch (value)
            {
                case TypeEnum.Organization:
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, "Organization");
                    return;
                case TypeEnum.Person:
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, "Person");
                    return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type TypeEnum");
        }

        public static readonly TypeEnumConverter Singleton = new TypeEnumConverter();
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

As for problems with sometime single, sometime array thing --> look here: [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: I think, that OP already has the proper structure, he clearly states the problem, that `director` property can be single item or an array

Comment: Thank you for responses. Yeah. exactly. When I use the `List<Person>` it's ok for movies with more than one director but for movies with one director, it gets error and vice versa. and the creator property is made by two different classes.

Comment: @Morteza - i've updated the response to cover the issue with single item vs array items.

Comment: @Piotr - That's interesting. let me try it. thank you